# How do I export users with their owner from Active Directory in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to fetch users from AD with the upn of their owners as an attribute. I call them with Get-ADUser and pipe them into Export-Csv, but the owner is not a standard AD property. How can I add them to the output?

Comment: "Owner"? I only know about "Manager" attribute, and that one is there.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to search who created a user, this can happen only by enabling logging and run an audit script every day.
Currently I am running a script that gives me all the users with all the attributes and I filter them by enabled )true/false) or object created timestamp so I can query the server logs to find out who did it.

Comment: You mean you want to get manager UPN? If yes, try this: `get-aduser username -Properties manager | select *,@{n="Manager";e={(Get-Aduser $_.Manager).UserPrincipalName}} -ExcludeProperty manager`

Comment: Are you looking for `Get-ADUser exampleuser | ForEach-Object {Get-ACL "AD:\$($_.DistinguishedName)" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Owner}`?

Comment: I do not want to get the manager, I want to get the creator. And it seems the proper autiting is not in place in my system.